# Update a table depending values in another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I need to update a field in a table if that id exists in another table in MySQL.

Table A:

```
ID Title
01 ABCDE
02 EFGHI
03 JKLMN
```

Table B:

```
ID Category
01 CAT1
01 CAT2
02 CAT2
03 CAT1
03 CAT3
```

In these tables A.ID = B.ID, and I need to update "Title" from Table A if in Table B Category = "CAT1", so, I have to update "Title" of ID 01 and ID 03, but not ID 02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableA a
SET Title = 'whatever'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND b.Category = 'CAT1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery.  You could do it like this:

```
UPDATE A
  SET Title = 'OPQRS'
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM B WHERE Category = 'CAT1')
```